# Swift Uncaught exception for spliviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I have a login view post which i have added a split view controller. I have segued the splitview controller to the Sign in Button. I get the following exception

```
2016-03-30 13:00:08.521 MyApp[1362:34711] -[MyApp.ViewController splitView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b12a190
2016-03-30 13:00:08.526 MyApp[1362:34711] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ViewController splitView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b12a190'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x002f5a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fa6e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x002fed63 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0023c6bd ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0023c28e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fbb0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    6   UIKit                               0x00ad8b79 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
    7   UIKit                               0x00ad8af8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    8   UIKit                               0x00c788f8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
    9   UIKit                               0x00c78c78 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 408
    10  UIKit                               0x00c77c7e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
    11  UIKit                               0x00b55182 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1095
    12  UIKit                               0x00b56220 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
    13  UIKit                               0x00afaf93 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
    14  UIKit                               0x00ad0668 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7802
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0020f6ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0020538b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x002047a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x002040e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00203efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x04755664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x047554a1 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x00ad6bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    23  EZTRade                             0x0010012c main + 140
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02a13a21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I went through the explanations in some links and tried a couple of things but in  vain.

Here is my storyboard[image]

Comment: Your first `UIViewController` should be of class `ViewController` or do you have a custom class for it?

Comment: Not custom class... It is ViewController